# GHCi environment dump

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is there is way in GHCi to basically get a state dump?  By this I mean a list of:

- All loaded operators along with it's precedence, associativity, and signature.
- All loaded classes.
- All loaded data, type, and newtype along with what classes they are instances of.
- All loaded functions with it's signature, and the class they belong to if they do.

Assuming that this is possible, is it also possible to do this at runtime, say during an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:browse` will give you most of this information. It shows

- Type signatures for functions and operators.
- Classes and their methods.
- Data types, newtypes and type synonyms, with constructors if they are in scope.

Without any arguments, it shows this information for the currently loaded module. You can also specify a different module.

```
Prelude> :browse Control.Applicative
class (Functor f) => Applicative f where
  pure :: a -> f a
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (*>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
  (<*) :: f a -> f b -> f a
...
```

To see more detail, including precedence and associativity for operators, as well as instances for a data type, use `:info`.

```
Prelude> :info (^)
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a   -- Defined in GHC.Real
infixr 8 ^
Prelude> :info Bool
data Bool = False | True    -- Defined in GHC.Bool
instance Bounded Bool -- Defined in GHC.Enum
instance Enum Bool -- Defined in GHC.Enum
instance Eq Bool -- Defined in GHC.Base
instance Ord Bool -- Defined in GHC.Base
instance Read Bool -- Defined in GHC.Read
```

These commands are also available while debugging.

For more information, type `:help` or see [the GHCi chapter of the GHC user's guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci.html).

Comment: I want something like this for the whole system not just a module.

Comment: @VansonSamuel: There is the form `:browse *Module`, which will show information for anything in scope in that module, i.e. all its imports as well as its exports. Perhaps that is closer to what you need?

Comment: I will try this.  Thanks @hammar this is like the fourth question you have helped me on. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are ways of getting this information. The problem is that, as far as I know, there is no way of filtering it exactly the way you want, but anyways here it is:

- If you want to see all identifiers, including classes, operators, Constructors, and Types, currently defined in ghci just press tab while you have the cursor on whitespace.
- If you want to know the precedence and associativity of an operator `*` just use

  ```
  :i *
  ```
- If you want to see what classes `M` is instance of just use

  ```
  :i M
  ```
- If you want to see the signature of a function `f` just use

  ```
  :i f
  ```

  If you write `:set -fbreak-on-exception` then ghci will break rather then fail when an exception is thrown and then you can use all of the above commands during an exception.